# nginx using proxy_pass very slow

Tags: nginx

I had an existing website hosted on a server, but we migrated this to a GKE instance.

I set up a simple nginx reverse proxy to use the new GKE do all the work, and the server just redirect as we do not have control over the DNS entry (it's a subdomain of the client's web site).

Accessing the gke-hosted site through a GKE ingress works perfectly (e.g. gke-backend.company.com)

This worked for a bit, and then it started being extremely slow (with some queries timeout-ing, but with the browser cache you can get a full page once you have reloaded multiple times).

here is my conf:

```
upstream backend {
  server gke-backend.company.com:443;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name website.client.com; 
  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header Host https://backend;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://backend;
  }
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I tried it with only the proxy_pass, and it works the same.

How do I find out the exact issue ?

Comment: slow data access can be caused by different parts, for example: server who serve the website is overloaded (for slow disk access or high performance usage) a vmstat could determinate it, a communication between the proxy and server is slow, how many firewall is present between the two server; client is slow to execute some JS on the page, and so on; try to begin to exclude one by one this and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `proxy_set_header Host https://backend;` did not work, I copy-pasted the complete host name in both `proxy_set_header` and `proxy_pass`, and now everythong works.

I have no idea what happened before though